# facing with Routing in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am facing setting routing properly as per my website URL. The URL is like http://staging.test.com/Partner/new/mp/Probook, 
where  "http://staging.test.com" is domain name. "Partner" is a VD pointing to an application(made in ASP.NET) running successfully. Also, another VD "new" is created which is pointing to my MVC application. "mp" just a string taken from us to let other know that it is different type of portal. "Probook" is another route value.

My Route config settings are as follows.

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "CoBrandMicroPortal",
          url: "mp/{mpid}/cp/{cpid}/{culture}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "MyPortal", action = "Index", culture = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "MicroPortal",
           url: "mp/{mpid}/{culture}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "MyPortal", action = "Index", culture = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyPortal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

When I am running the URL, I am getting 404 error. That means the portal is not running with the "new" VD. The portal is working if the URL is "http://staging.test.com/new/mp/Probook".
with the upper settings. Can anyone try to understand the problem and give me any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: is `new` a nested virtual directory?  E.g., `new` must be under `Partner`

Comment: Can you please post the flow of your application in IIS structure ?

Comment: yes ps2goat, new is also VD under Partner.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have rewrite rules that are interfering with your routing settings. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297178/asp-net-mvc-routing-not-working-in-virtual-directory#3304983).